# What are the Arena Tiers in Fire Emblem Heroes?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

In Fire Emblem Heroes, the all players are in some tier, but I can't figure out what determines this.  For instance, the first week, I (and I think all players) was in tier 1, the second week I was in tier 2, and this week I've been in tier 3.  From what I've found, you only fight players in the same tier as you, but I haven't been able to figure out what determines tier each week.

If it helps anyone figure it out, I've been scoring around 3100 - 3600 in offense each week and 250 - 270 in defense, but have been unranked.

Comment: It's probably just being promoted to the next tier if you do relatively well in the season. It's too early to know if there's a ceiling yet and I too have been doing well in general (in intermediate battles) to see if there's a drop or even not advance. From what I could tell, if you don't participate in arena battles, you don't advance.

Comment: Yeah, I was guessing it was something along those lines, but I was wondering if someone had figured out more details.

Comment: You're not limited to only fighting people in your tier - I'm tier 4 and occasionally still have tier 1's as options. I do think it's limited to one level of promotion per season, so I don't think anyone's above tier 4 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 1.3.0 update brings us this chart depicting the tier system and how the new rewards work.] I am pretty sure that if you score over a certain amount, you get moved up. Also, starting from 1.3.0, once you reach tier 8 (there is a total of 20 tiers) you can move down if you are not participating/scoring well.